# Как построить iframe ссылку по координатам с картой центр которой, указывает на эти координаты?

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-embed

Стоит задача открыть iframe и передать ему сгенерированную ссылку по координатам подобно следующей:

https://yandex.ru/maps/?l=map&ll=54.484167N,72.878889E&spn=54.484167,72.878889&z=15
при попытке это сделать получаю следующую ошибку:

Refused to display 'https://yandex.ru/maps/?l=map&ll=54%C2%B029%E2%80%B23%E2%80%B3N,72%C2%B052%E2%80%B244%E2%80%B3E&spn=54.484167,72.878889&z=15&output=embed' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'.

Подскажите пожалуйста, существует ли способ сгенерировать правильную ссылку по имеющимся координатам, чтобы она обращалась к не запрещенному контенту?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сам сайт Яндекс.Карты нельзя открыть в iframe и встроить на чужой сервис. Для вашей задачи есть специальный Виджет Яндекс.Карт.

**Где взять код Виджета**

- Заходите на Яндекс.Карты
- Ищете нужную организацию или строите маршрут
- В меню `=` выбираете пункт "Поделиться"
- Забираете код для сайта

Свою ссылку тоже можно "подставить" в Виджет, но надо понимать, что у Яндекс.Карт нет публичной url-схемы - параметры и формат значений могут меняться, а значит вся ваша генерация может в любой момент сломаться.

Код будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
<iframe src="https://yandex.ru/map-widget/v1/?ll=37.624513%2C55.748635&z=12" width="560" height="400" frameborder="1" allowfullscreen="true"></iframe>
```

[Посмотреть пример](https://jsfiddle.net/dcLygumj/)

Comment: Большое спасибо, я хотел узнать, а куда нужно будет смотреть, чтобы привести ссылку в актуальное состояние в момент когда все сломается?

Comment: Есть ещё вопрос, возможно ли послать параметр в url который будет ставить pin на карту в точку указанную координатами?

Comment: @user2676237 я взяла ссылку просто с Яндекс.Карт, точки там сейчас задаются параметром pt. Но я бы на Вашем месте сделала карту на JS API, где есть обратная совместимость и можно всегда показывать то, что нужно. Способ с Я.Картами очень ненадежный.